# Is "tempesta artica" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

I need to register a name and would like to know if "tempesta artica" in Italian (should be "arctic storm" in English) is grammatically correct and spelled right. Must be in singular form. Google Translate says so but I wouldn't want to rely just on Google for such an important decision.

Comment: **Tempesta artica** is both grammatically correct and spelled right.

Comment: @abarisone Please, add an answer.

Answer (score 4):

**Tempesta artica** is both grammatically correct and spelled right.

In fact the noun **tempesta** (storm) is feminine singular and the adjective **artica** (arctic) is consequently adapted according to the noun gender and grammatical number.